# How to enable Internet Games in Civ4 BTS on MacOS?

Tags: civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I am playing Civilization IV BTS from Steam on MacOS, which is still using GameSpy as Internet game service provider. But GameSpy has shut down several years ago.
So is there any way to hold Internet games?

Comment: it should work according to [this](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/201967707-2K-Online-Server-Migration-from-GameSpy-Technology)

Comment: I re-installed the game in Steam but it is still not working. It seems that Mac and Windows are using different versions. On Windows, the multiplayer mode works perfectly..